# How do i set max sum of lines between 2 TextViews

Tags: android, kotlin, android-databinding

I have a little problem in my project and I hope you could help me with it.

I need to create a view which contains 2 textviews and max sum text line count must be 4.
For example:

If the textview on the top contains 4 lines, the second one must not be shown.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EvNtq.png)

If the textview on the top contains 3 lines, the second one must have only 1.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2epDA.png)

If the textview on the top contains a line, the second one can contains 3 lines as maximum.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/13FJ5.png)

The xml should be something like that but idk how to set references to configure this behavior.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<View
    android:id="@+id/text_space"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:background="#FFEB3B"/>

<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
    android:id="@+id/text_one"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet."
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0"
    app:layout_constraintHeight_default="wrap"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/text_space"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/text_space"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/text_space"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/text_space" />

<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
    android:id="@+id/text_two"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:textColor="#3F51B5"
    android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus id consequat purus suspendisse potenti. Fusce dapibus diam vitae facilisis aliquet. Etiam eu ante augue."
    android:maxLines="3"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0"
    app:layout_constraintHeight_default="wrap"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/text_space"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/text_space"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/text_space"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/text_one" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Anyone knows how to do this?

BTW, I use databinding and kotlin in my project and It'd be perfect if i could control this from xml.

Regards,

Comment: Is your textview dynamically updated or are they filled one time and then doesn't change ?

Comment: Could you add some code in order we get an idea, so that we can help out ?

Comment: @Skylek Those text are filled only one time

Comment: @Pako1 I added some information else to the post

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.